# TSL/SSL configuration of Spring HTTP invoker

Tags: spring, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

i have a question regarding TSL/SSL. I am programming a client-server application using Spring HTTP-Invoker. The client is a "classic" desktop application which is distributed via webstart. The server will be running on Tomcat/JBoss. I already tested the invocation with a test-service and it worked like a charm, but now i am trying to use SSL to encrypt the channel. I will post my client-code for clarification:

```
<bean id="checkFuntionalityService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/test-server/remoting/checkFuntionalityService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="at.test.common.remote.CheckFuntionalityService" />
    <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor">
            <property name="readTimeout" value="5000" />
            <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried this with a self-signed certificate, which i put into my cacerts store and it works, but i still have some questions:

Is there a way to use a different keystore/truststore on client-side (e.g. classpath:config/test.jks)? My plan is to put my certificate into a new keystore, which i would put into the client project. Is this possible and if so: how can i use this store on client-side? I know a better way would be a certificate from a trusted CA, but this is not an option atm. Also i can't put the key in every users cacerts store. Any hints for me?

I am also open for any kind of suggestions. Shall i stick to HTTP-Invoker? I could also use Spring RMI-Invoker, i understand that pretty much the only difference is that the HTTP-Invoker uses HTTP-Post to transfer the binary content, which is more unlikely to be blocked by a firewall, right? But what if firewall configuration is not an issue for me? Shall i use RMI or stick with HTTP-Invoker even then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Problem already solved! I kind of mixed up keystore with truststore. So if you found this question and look for an answer, take a look at: [Trust Store vs Key Store - creating with keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool). In short: you have to create a certificate which you put in a keystore for the server and in a truststore for the client. Well, essentially there is no real different between keystore and truststore, the only difference is that you use different System-properties to define them in your program. (e.g. javax.net.ssl.trustStore for the truststore). Thats where i messed up!
>
> I am still interested in reasons on whether or not to use Spring HTTP Invoker though.