# 2way ssl with java

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying at write a java program that hits a url over ssl, and prints out the response to find out if the application on this port is running or not. We are using 2way ssl. I am fairly new to working with ssl and java security. Right now I am getting this error

> Remote host closed connection during handshake

I am using this command to run the program

> `java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=rs.truststore  TmpUtil`

Is there a way to find out what am I doing wrong and where exactly is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally debug an SSL/TLS connection that uses the JSSE in Java using the `javax.net.debug` system property. You'll find more details in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html).

Since you're after client-certificate authentication, it's most likely that your application needs a keystore to be configured. You'll find some details about the difference between *keystore* and *truststore* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643), and in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) of course.