# CXF Client With SSL Throws SSLHandshakeException

Tags: ssl, cxf, sslhandshakeexception

I am facing getting SSLhandshakeException while I try to consume a CXF webservice using a CXF client over HTTPS connection.

The web service requires SSL connection therefore I have PKCS 12 key store which is referenced in the java code directly with the password as below.

### System property configuration in java code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/user/test-client.p12");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "AbcgfhYgb");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl, handshake");
```

### CXF client configuration in cxf.xml

```
<jaxws:client id="CService" serviceClass="com..cws.CService"
        address="https://developer.webservice.com/test" />

<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
    </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

### Exception Thrown on executing the client

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://developer.webservice.com/test: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
                at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:50)
                at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
                at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
                ... 53 more
        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
                at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
                at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1748)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:991)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1175)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1202)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1186)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:979)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:168)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1233)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
                at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
                at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1295)
                ... 65 more
```

Can anyone suggest solution for accessing the web service using CXF client with SSL.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation on creating a CXF-based client leaves something to be desired and the few sources that I could find on the web describe different ways to do this. Yours is yet another one, as it references the SSL certificate via `System.setProperty()` instead of using the formal Apache approach via `<http:conduit`. I am facing similar difficulties [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20554567/1864054), perhaps you could get an idea from my approach (which is throwing a different type of exception and I haven't solved this yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the JDK cacerts as a trustore manager which consist of the CA certificate for the SSL certificate. Also, add the keystore which consist of the SSL certifcate as below.

```
     <http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="testkey">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit"
                file="<keystore path>" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit"
                file="<cacert path>" />
        </sec:trustManagers>
    </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
    <http-conf:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration will enable CXF client to consume JAXWS service over SSL ( https):

```
  <http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit" >
    <http-conf:tlsClientParameters 
        useHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory="true"     
    />
  </http-conf:conduit>
```

Check: 
1. That certificate has been impoprted in the consumer for producer
2. Additionlay if you have a problem where there is a mismatch between hostname and the one in certificate you can use disableCNCheck="true". However this flag is not recomended for Producation