# Java keystore maintenance utilities

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, keystore

We are using the below line in our shell script file :

```
Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/proj/xxx/www/cgi-bin/xxx_cacerts
```

The xxx_cacerts file contains SSL certificate information. 
As we are about to upgrade we tried changing that file as per the latest one given in our organization.

For this we need to know what is "Java keystore maintenance utilities" in order to make changes in application side.

With this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/secret-key-import-java) i understand a bit . Can any one explain in details what exactly Java Keystore means?

Comment: Are you asking "What is a Java Keystore"? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Am asking what is Key Store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Keystore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202046/what-is-keystore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a keystore is a repository of certificates located on the file system. See a more detailed definition here: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=what+is+a+keystore&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Also this SO question [What is Keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202046/what-is-keystore) I believe should be helpful.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer duplicate questions. Especially when you found the question that this question is a duplicate of. You should flag this question as a duplicate of the question you linked to. (I would, but I voted to close with another reason).

Comment: @ArtjomB.The question Josh found, while related to this question, is not a duplicate.  See my comment answering you under my answer to the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your xxx_cacerts file is a Java keystore.  It contains keys and certificate information.

The Java utility for managing keystores is called keytool.  Documentation on keytool may be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html

Comment: It is discouraged to answer duplicate questions. Especially when Josh C found the question that this question is a duplicate of. You should vote to close this question as a duplicate of the question Josh C linked to. (I would, but I voted to close with another reason).

Comment: @ArtjomB.The question Josh found is not a duplicate of this question.  He found a question which asked about the keystore.  This question is actually about utilities to manage the keystore, namely Java keytool.  They are two different things.

Comment: That's only partly true, because the second highest voted answer also describes the keytool.

Comment: @ArtjomB.The fact that an answer on a different question happens to cover more than that question asked does not make the questions duplicates.

Comment: @WarrenDew I believe the question asked was "Can anyone explain in detail what exactly Java Keystore means?" When asked for clarification, he stated "What is Key Store?" The way I understood the description, the "maintenance utilities" comment was simply background for his more fundamental question, similar to the -D also being background information.

Comment: @JoshC I believe the asker of the question is unclear on the difference between a Java keystore, which stores data, and the Java keytool program, which is a maintenance utility for Java keystores.  I think he actually wants the latter, even though he thinks he wants the former, which is why I gave the answer I think he needs, and voted against closing the question.  Reasonable people could disagree on this, though.

Comment: @WarrenDew Fair enough, makes sense.