# How to update app with Google Play and force download

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I'm using android studio. I have developed an app and now I want to upload it to Google Play. I have a license and I have uploaded an app before, but I didn't really know what I was doing at that time.

What I want is to upload my app to Google Play, and then upade it without losing the reviews and rating. How do I do that?

And, what is the best way to force a user to download an update? I am going to upload the app to Google Play and to Amazon Appstore (for android), so a link to Google Play or something similar is maybe not the best solution. I was thinking - a toast message "please update the app". What do you think?

Comment: the only way I know to force a user to update is by showing a UI blocking popup whenever a user opens a deprecated version of your app. Like how WhatsApp does it

Comment: Great! I'm using it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updating an existing apk on Google Play Store:**

1) Go to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)

2) Select **All applications** in that select **"Your Application"**

3) Select **Upload APK**.

4) Choose from the Production, Beta, or Alpha channels and select **Upload your APK**.

It take few hours to publish update. [more information about upload, publish, etc.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en)

**Forcing users to update:** There are three things

1) It is not possible in Google Play Store, unless user have set automatic update on.

2) You can use external library like [UpdateChecker](https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker), [AppUpdater](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater), etc.

3) You can change your application structure in that way that whenever user starts you application internal contents get update. (This is not a feasible option, I guess)

**[What is KeyStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202046/what-is-keystore)**

It is used to build singed apk.

Keep your keystore in a secure location. If you lose your keystore, you'll need to publish the app with a new package name and a new key. If you need to do this, you should also unpublish the original app and update its description

Comment: Amazing! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this library, actually it provides what you want with simple approach.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3094

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a new version of your app to the Play Store, you will not lose any of the prior ratings for that app.

You can't force users to update your app. It is fully under their control. Some people may have automatic updates turned on, but for those who do not, they have to choose to receive the update.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the key store and other things that might be crucial?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The keystore has nothing to do with this.  You always have to sign with the same key in order to publish an update.  That never changes.

Comment: So I should save the keystore somewhere. Alright thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google added this new feature you can add to your app to force in-app update based on if you want the update immediate or flexible

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java