# Is truststore a pure Java terminology?

Tags: java, ssl, truststore

When I search "truststore" on YouTube, I got the following video as the first hit. It is about Java.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur9LlNOYnRg

A Google search also mostly returns Java webpages.

Is this a pure Java concept? How can in be explained in the context of SSL/TLS without using Java?

Comment: I mean, from what I understand, a trust store stores certificates. I'm not sure that I understand your question though. Are you asking whether certificate storage can only be done using Java?

Comment: No. I am asking the specific term "truststore", as I only see it in the context of Java, instead of the general context of SSL/TLS. If it is specific to Java, I am wondering why java people create such a unique term whereas SSL/TLS has more general implementation in C. They could just made a wrapper on top of the C code. I don't understand why java people reinvent the wheel and create new terminologies for almost the same thing in other contexts.

Comment: Is "certificate store" an equivalent but more commonly referred terminology outside the scope of java? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=concepts-certificate-stores

Comment: Or there are many variant terminology that refers basically the same thing?

Comment: Trust store is just a word (or phrase) and anybody is allowed to use it. That said I see it used mainly in Java, and it is specifically used to refer to a keystore containing trusted certificates. Your comments about Java "reinventing" the wheel and about a "general implementation in C" don't make any sense to me.

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase your question a little so that it doesn't look like it's asking for external resources (which seems to have been the reason for closure).

Comment: @Bruno  zero298,
President James K. Polk and
Magnas look like a\*s h\*l\*s. They could be more constructive just like you to rephrase it. I am sure many questions got closed can be rephrased in a way that it would not be considered as to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that certificates are not used only for SSL/TLS, and Java used them for codesigning almost a decade before it implemented SSL/TLS, although that has become much less important following the floppage of 'deployment' (i.e. automatically download code from everywhere and run it). Also, while Java 'could just make a wrapper on  C code' (especially since the JVM, without which Java doesn't really exist, is all C and C++), they didn't; the SSL/TLS implementation provided by (standard = Sun-now-Oracle or OpenJDK) Java, called JSSE (Java Secure Socket Extension), is written in Java. The cryptographic primitives it uses are accessed using JCA, the Java Cryptography Architecture, and in *most* cases are also implemented in Java, although JCA providers *can* use 'native' code (C or C++) or external hardware (PKCS11 devices). (However, Apache Tomcat, and TTBOMK things based on it like Jboss Wildfly, has a 'native' option that *instead* of JSSE uses APR, Apache Portable Runtime, which in turn uses OpenSSL, which is C.)

That said, every implementation of anything relying on PKI, including but not limited to SSL/TLS, normally uses and needs something that stores (or otherwise persistently holds) trusted CA certs -- sometimes limited to only root certs, and sometimes called 'root' certs even when they aren't actually roots -- but I don't know of anything besides Java that calls this specifically 'truststore'.

NSS has a 'certificate database' usually(?) backed by a 'module', Microsoft has a *set* of 'certificate stores' only some of which are 'trusted', Apple has a 'KeyChain' (although I found a [few](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202858) [cases](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132) they *describe* it  as a trust store). And GnuPG in S/MIME mode has a 'keybox' with an associated but separate 'trustlist' (while in PGP mode, which is WoT instead, it has a 'keyring' and 'trustdb'). OpenSSL (and things using it) can have a 'CA file' and/or 'CA directory (or path)'; some things using OpenSSL refer to the CA file as a 'CA bundle', 'CA list', or 'root list'.

FWIW, the ["Common CA Database" project](https://www.ccadb.org/), an attempt by Mozilla to coordinate the several programs that maintain nearly duplicate lists/stores of CAs, describes them as 'Root Stores' or 'Root Store Operators', although it explicitly allows (and often requires) the database to include intermediate CAs, i.e. *not* roots. Bleah.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But it seems the terminology is really a mess :). Without your clarification, it will be very confusing to understand them. But now I know that they are basically the same.

Comment: You should vote open the post. There is no ground to close the question.

Comment: The closest "official term" for all this I can think of is "trust anchors" as mentioned in [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280). That said, every vendor/project has its own terminology indeed. Java itself can use [confusing terminology when it comes to keystores/truststores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26888423/372643).