# Remove alias from cacerts file [collection of trusted certificate authority (CA) certificates] - jdk 11

Tags: java, linux, security, client-certificates

I am using linux and I want to remove reference of the certificate e.g alias from `cacerts` file, which is a collection of trusted certificate authority (CA) certificates. But I don't remember the name of the alias.
Below is JDK information

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

When I list the entries form cacerts with keytool, it shows below type of output.

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Output

> verisignclass3publicprimarycertificationauthority-g3, Apr 2, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): EB:04:CF:5E:B1:F3:9A:FA:76:2F:2B:B1:20:F2:96:CB:A5:20:C1:B9:7D:B1:58:95:65:B8:1C:B9:A1:7B:72:44
> verisignclass3publicprimarycertificationauthority-g4, Apr 2, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 69:DD:D7:EA:90:BB:57:C9:3E:13:5D:C8:5E:A6:FC:D5:48:0B:60:32:39:BD:C4:54:FC:75:8B:2A:26:CF:7F:79
> verisignclass3publicprimarycertificationauthority-g5, Apr 2, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 9A:CF:AB:7E:43:C8:D8:80:D0:6B:26:2A:94:DE:EE:E4:B4:65:99:89:C3:D0:CA:F1:9B:AF:64:05:E4:1A:B7:DF
> verisignuniversalrootcertificationauthority, Apr 2, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 23:99:56:11:27:A5:71:25:DE:8C:EF:EA:61:0D:DF:2F:A0:78:B5:C8:06:7F:4E:82:82:90:BF:B8:60:E8:4B:3C
> xrampglobalcaroot, Apr 2, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): CE:CD:DC:90:50:99:D8:DA:DF:C5:B1:D2:09:B7:37:CB:E2:C1:8C:FB:2C:10:C0:FF:0B:CF:0D:32:86:FC:1A:A2

My question is that how can I remove alias from `cacerts` file, when I don't remember the alias name. Is there any other pointer, using which I know which entry to delete from `cacerts`.

Comment: You can see the alias of every certificate by using the argument `-v` (verbose output): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/keytool.html#commands-for-displaying-data

Answer (score 2):

The fact you're mentioning `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts` suggests you're using a `cacerts` file managed by your Linux distribution (presumably based on RedHat/CentOS).

Removing the specific certificate from that `cacerts` file is indeed possible with `keytool` manually. However, it's likely to be re-generated, and possibly placed back into that file the next time `update-ca-trust` is executed automatically (e.g. package upgrade) or not.

When using the distribution-managed `cacerts` file, it's generally better to use the distribution's mechanism.

On RedHat/CentOS-based distributions, [this can be done by managing individual certificates in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and using `update-ca-trust`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456475/adding-a-root-certification-authority-to-a-java-application).

On Debian/Ubuntu-based distributions, [there is an equivalent with certificates in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244923/how-to-remove-a-ca-certificate-in-debian), assuming the `ca-certificates-java` package is installed (and then, you can run `update-ca-certificates`).

---

As a side-note, you've tagged your question with `client-certificate`.

Client-certificates (and more so their matching private key, i.e. `PrivateKeyEntry` entries) normally don't belong in the `cacerts` file at all, which [is a "keystore"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26888423/372643) used as [a "truststore"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643) (typically used as the default truststore for all Java applications running on that system). Those belong to a "keystore used as a keystore", not a "keystore used as a truststore" (which shouldn't contain private keys).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete certificate reference from cacerts entries via alias name and forgot the alias name, then another pointer from cacerts file is the Certificate fingerprints. Check the fingerprints from the certificate and find the fingerprints from cacerts entries.
Here is a full example.
First list the entries from the certificate keystore.

```
keytool -list -keystore ./keystore.pfx
```

It will show output like this:

> Keystore type: PKCS12 Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> te-b6b910d1-a1e2-4a51-b3c8-2c0199d393a3, Dec 7, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256):
> 37:01:C3:18:96:D9:54:A3:F6:B6:75:39:2A:5C:61:F9:EF:41:21:4C:E5:BF:6B:37:70:6C:EB:4F:50:3F:90:EB

Note down fingerprint value, i.e `37:01:C3:18:96:D9:54:A3:F6:B6:75:39:2A:5C:61:F9:EF:41:21:4C:E5:BF:6B:37:70:6C:EB:4F:50:3F:90:EB`

Now list down cacerts entries in a text file.

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts -storepass changeit > output.txt
```

Now open the text file with some editor, e.g vi or vim or nano, and find the fingerprint value.
In this file you will see below two lines

```
mykey, May 20, 2022, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 37:01:C3:18:96:D9:54:A3:F6:B6:75:39:2A:5C:61:F9:EF:41:21:4C:E5:BF:6B:37:70:6C:EB:4F:50:3F:90:EB
```

Now you have found the alias name i.e mykey. So you can delete the certificate entry to cacerts with below command

```
keytool -delete -alias mykey -keystore /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts -storepass changeit --noprompt
```

if you run the above command again, it will show below error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <mykey> does not exist.
```

So with this example, now you are able to find the alias name from cacerts using fingerprints and able to delete the alias from cacerts entries.