# NoSuchAlgorithmException: der KeyStore not available

Tags: java, post, httpclient, restlet

I am trying to do a `POST` call to a secure website:

**Steps:**

1) Go to https://www.mywebsite.com (For reference)

2) Export the keystore of the above website to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security`.

3) Import it to cacerts to add a self signed signature using keytool as

```
keytool -import -alias my-cert -file c:\cert.crt -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

After doing the above steps I used the following program:

```
String keystorePathAndName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\security\\mykeystore";
String keystoreType = "der";

String keystorePass = "";

Integer port = 8089;
if (System.getProperty("port") != null) {
    port = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("port"));
}
// Create a server listening on port 8089
Component component = new Component();
Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTPS, port);
Series<Parameter> params = server.getContext().getParameters();
params.add("keystorePath", keystorePathAndName);
params.add("keystoreType", keystoreType);

params.add("keystorePassword", keystorePass);


component.getDefaultHost().attach("/Simulator",new UserApplication());
component.start();
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: der not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:616)
    at org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:299)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpsServerHelper.start(HttpsServerHelper.java:92)
    at org.restlet.Server.start(Server.java:579)
    at org.restlet.Component.startServers(Component.java:642)
    at org.restlet.Component.start(Component.java:567)
    at com.user.app.userapp.main.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:78)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: der KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:613)
    ... 6 more
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to the Lolo's answer, I am not getting `PKCS12` OR `JKS` formats when trying to save the keystore.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the exception message: "der not found" upon calling `KeyStore.getInstance()` means that `der` is not a known format for your key store. You shoud try one of the known formats, such as `JKS` (the default for Oracle's JVM) or `PKCS12`. See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540061/524900) for more details on keystore formats.

**Edit:**

As shown in your screenshot, the file you are saving is a certificate file. Assuming that you then imported it into a truststore using Oracle's '`keytool`' and that you didn't specify the truststore format, then the default format `JKS`for Oracle's JVM should be used in your code, instead of `der`:

```
String keystoreType = "JKS";
```

Comment: Please check my update in the question. My save dialog is not giving me the options to save as type `JKS` or `PKSC12`.

Comment: I'm confused. Your screenshot shows that you're saving a certificate, not a key- or trust- store. You need to effectively save the certificate file (which may have the ".der" extension), _then import it into a truststore_ with an appropriate format (using `keytool`). Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes this is what I am doing. I saved it as a `.der` and then imported using keytool `keytool -import -alias my-cert -file c:\cert.crt -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts` then my code gives exception as I mentioned `NoSuchAlgorithmException: der KeyStore not available`.