# Is having a certificate in java keystore the same as having it in windows keystore?

Tags: java, windows, security, keystore, keytool

My questions are :

1. What is the difference between having a certificate in WINDOWS
   keystore and having it in JAVA keystore ?
2. In a machine if a certificate is imported to WINDOWS keystore,
   does JVM know it automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536848/keystore-type-which-one-to-use                                                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool

Comment: Maybe you guys should read more than just the headline... None of the linked questions has an answer to his questions.

Comment: the two suggested answers doesn't respond to my question