# java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException Java refuses to connect

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

I am writing a program for work and I have been stumped on this issue for almost a week now. The program keeps throwing the same exception no matter what I do.

I have looked up every known resource and every question related to this problem and every attempt and suggestion has failed. According to 90% of posts I've come across, it says that I should use `keytool` to add the certificate to my `keystore`. This is what I have attempted:

```
keytool -import -alias abc -file ~/Downloads/\*.gcsip.nl   #=> gcsip.nl is the certificate I downloaded from the browser.
```

It asked me for a password, I added it, and my app still doesn't work when I run it. I looked into "How to import certificates into Eclipse project" and they recommended that I do the same command. I have never dealt with Java certificates before, but it's been a true absolute nightmare.

The weird part was that the app was working perfectly fine one day, and when I came into work, this exception started happening. I literally changed nothing.

I've also looked into the other `Caused by:` exceptions including `Invalid keystore format` and have had no luck solving that either. Honestly, even after reading the Oracle docs throughly, I still have no idea what a keystore is, does, and is supposed to look like.

I am just looking for someone who's had experience with this issue who can elaborate (like I'm 5) on how keystore works and how I can fix it. Any help is extremely appreciated.

I should note that I am not very Java savvy.

Here's my StackTrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:255)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:409)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at GCollect.authorize(GCollect.java:102)
at TestCase.main(TestCase.java:20)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:972)
    at GCollect.authorize(GCollect.java:100)
    ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: The last "Caused by" part in a stacktrace is the root cause. So something is indeed wrong with your keystore file. And a keystore is just like the name suggests a file that stores (cryptographic) keys (and certificates and so on). The format you want is probably the JKS keystore format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536848/keystore-type-which-one-to-use - I don't know what's wrong though. The error only says it's wrong. You could try if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685548/java-keytool-easy-way-to-add-server-cert-from-url-port results in something.

Comment: i have never come across .nl extension files for certificates. The common formats are cer, crt, der, pkcs (.p7b, .p7r or .spc), p12. Is it possible for you to export the certficate in any of these formats.

Comment: @pawindergupta I'm not sure. I don't believe so but I'll look into it.