# BKS not found when configuration in jBoss 7.1

Tags: ssl, configuration, jboss, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x

jBoss - 7.1
OS - Win 10
To add ssl certificate to jBoss use this command `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA` its genarates `.keystore` file in configuration folder in jBoss home. But when it runs gives a error message

"BKS not found"
I reffer follwing tutorial for configuraion https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/ssl-howto.html

This is not jBoss web.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related with the fact that keytool tries to instantiate a **BKS** keystore but no Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) is able to provide such an implementation. Please bear in mind that BKS keystore type has been implemented by the BouncyCastle CSP!

Answer (score 1):

Look if you somewhere have *storetype* defined. When creating keystore depending on the JDK version *JKS* or *JCEKS* is default. JBoss afaik wants to see JKS. So try to create keystore maybe with option -storetype JKS. 
Or maybe in your JBoss config the usage of storetype BKS is mandated?

See also [Keystore type: which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536848/keystore-type-which-one-to-use)