# Curl cacert to Java HttpClient equivalent

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, keytool, jks

I wonder if I am able to make a connection using curl like the following command,

> curl --cacert some.pem https://someurl.com/resource

How do I convert this to httpclient code? I understands I need to convert the pem file and create a new keystore, etc. But all these openssl, keytool commands, keystore, truststore confuses me, I don't know which one to use and in which order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a keystore (which you'll use as a trust store) from the PEM file. This can be done as follows.

```
keytool -import -file cacert.pem -alias myca -keystore truststore.jks
```

You then need to use this keystore as a truststore.

If you wish to do this for a specific connection only, you should follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/372643).

If you want to do this for all connections in your application (or at least those that don't change the default), you can use the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` (and related) system properties (see the [Customization section of the JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)). The problem if you want to do this for your entire application is that default trusted CAs won't be included. An easy way around this is to make a copy of the `cacerts` file bundled with your JRE and use it as a starting point for `truststore.jks`.

Alternatively, you can import the certificate directly into the global `cacerts` file, but this will make that certificate trusted by default on all applications running on this JRE.

(You can also find more about the distinction between keystore and truststore in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643).)