# What is the equivalent to --cacerts in Scala or Java?

Tags: scala, rest, ssl

In my development and qa environments, I will be hitting a rest endpoint using internally signed certs. The policy where I work is to put internal certs in a separate bundle on our Linux servers.

The following works perfectly well in curl:

`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --negotiate --cacert /etc/pki/tls/out-internal-bundle.pem -u : "https://<dev or qa root>/api/profile/8461869a8b6e4558b20b14411337440b"`

My actual client for this endpoint is written in Scala, however. Currently I'm making my call using `scala.io.Source`:

```
val url = s"$baseUrl/data-profiler/$id"
using(Source.fromURL(url)) { source => {
  val result = source.mkString
  val jsonAst = result.parseJson
  jsonAst.convertTo[Job]
}}
```

I would like to figure out how, in my dev and qa environments, to use our internal bundle. Anyone doing that in Scala or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the "truststore" used by the JVM, with the "`javax.net.ssl.trustStore`" option when you launch java, i.e.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/tls/out-internal-bundle.jks ...
```

(`sbt` will take the same `-D` argument if you are using SBT to launch your app)

You'll need to get your CA certs into JKS format.

See:

- [Curl cacert to Java HttpClient equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043033/curl-cacert-to-java-httpclient-equivalent)
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager

Answer (score -2):

I would entirely recommend you to use Gatling for this kind of things. Gatling is a really cool framework for load-testing and it provides support for many protocols like jms, jdbc, and of course http among others. Please take a look on it here http://gatling.io/#/ (This framework is build on Scala) and it provides support for the things that you are searching for

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. If he switches to Gatling, he will still need to configure the Gatling client to provide the internal CA config.

Comment: Taking a dependency on a load testing framework is a non-starter.