# Use certificate in java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I've been trying several solutions to use a password protected p12 cert in my soap client (authentication). I cant get it to work. Could anyone please point me in the right direction. My latest test:

1. `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mycert.p12 -destkeystore cert/cacerts -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass 123456789 -deststorepass changeit -srcalias 1 -destalias mycert`
2. `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","cert/cacerts");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");`

Result:

fatal, description = certificate_unknown

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first look into the [difference between a keystore and a truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643). If you want to use you PKCS#12 file for client authentication, it's as a keystore you need to use it. (You may also need to set the truststore properties if the server certificate can't be trusted by the default CAs, but that's a different problem.)

You shouldn't need to convert you p12 file into JKS at all.

If your client uses the system properties to initialise its SSL context (check its documentation), you should be able to configure your p12 file by pointing `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` to it, setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` to `PKCS12` and setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` correctly. In most cases, these properties should be set before any SSL connection is attempted, since they will be only read once.

Comment: thanks, I think I need a truststore since it is not a trusted certificate? Could you please provide me with som lines on how to add my p12 file into a truststore?

Comment: Your client certificate (and private key) will always go in the keystore. It's the server certificate that may need to be imported into a truststore.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: It might already be trusted by default. Do you get any exception when you use the default trust store settings?

Comment: It isnt trusted. I managed to figure it out. I exported the cert from my keychain on the computer and imported it in the truststore. Tried to export from the webbrowser, but that didnt work. thanks.