# WebLogic SSL: No identity key/certificate entry was found under alias in keystore

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore, weblogic11g

I'm struggling with the following problem.

I've been provided of a certificate and I added it to the default java keystore as follows:

```
keytool -import -alias finesceKey -keystore cacerts -trustcacerts -file certificate.cer
```

Now, I've both configured weblogic keystore and SSL parts in order to make it point the cacerts file, but when my application runs I receive the following error:

> No identity key/certificate entry >was found under alias finesceKey in keystore /home/weblogic/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29-R28.2.0->4.1.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts on server ManagedServer1

I'm pretty sure that paths, names and password are correct, infact if I use the keytool for listing the certificates by alias name, I get the expected result.

I tried to import again the certificate using a different alias name, and configure WL accordingly, but without success.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use this keystore as [a keystore, not as a truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643).

The keytool command you've used only imported the certificate, not its private key, which makes it useless as a keystore.

`cacerts` is generally used a truststore, and should really not contain any private key: don't use it as your Weblogic keystore, use a separate keystore if you need one.