# How can i use *.p12 certificate in grails for establising https-connection?

Tags: grails, ssl, https

I am trying connect to my backend through https.
I have 2 certificats *.p12 and *.cer. I'm imported with command(see in code)
I imported key with command:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore bonus-testagent.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore truststore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

my code is(grails service):

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSSLFactory() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    String keystoreFile = 'D:\\grails_wide\\certificates\\truststore.jks'
    File binaryFile = new File(keystoreFile);
    InputStream is = binaryFile.newInputStream()
    if (is == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String password = "****";
    keyStore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
    is.close();


    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    return ctx.getSocketFactory();
}

def accountInfo(String cardNumber, Cookie[] cookies) {
    String urlStr = "https://app-domain.com";
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLFactory());
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", WebUtils.buildCookiesHeader(cookies))
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    def response = stringBuffer.toString();
```

But it has error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SunCertPathBuilderException occurred when processing request: [POST] /club/account
unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Stacktrace follows:
Message: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In string:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Using `is` as a variable name in Grails might not be such a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you generally don't need to convert your PKCS#12 (.p12) file into a JKS store, you can use the `PKCS12` keystore type directly.

Secondly, a `.p12` file is generally not to be used as a truststore, but as a keysore instead. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643) for the difference between keystore and truststore, for example.) The `.p12` file will contain private key material, which doesn't belong in a truststore.

What you've done here is replacing the default truststore with your `.p12` file, so it can only validate against the certificate in your `.p12` file when it connects remotely (instead of validating against CA certificates). Hence, it fails with "*unable to find valid certification path to requested target*".

Presumably, you were trying to connect with a client-certificate. In this case, you'll need to use that `.p12` file as a *keystore*. To do this:

1. (Optional) If you want to load your `.p12` directly, use `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")` instead. (You wouldn't have needed that keytool conversion.)
2. Use it with a `KeyManagerFactory` instead of the `TrustManagerFactory`. The init password will be the password for the key itself, which is the same as the store key in PKCS#12.
3. Use `ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null)`. The second `null` parameter will use the JRE's default trust store (assuming your server is trusted this way).