# Storing server certificate in HTTPS client trust store

Tags: ssl, communication

I have a use case where I am trying to connect to an HTTPS server. Initially I was thinking to use JRE cacert file for SSL handshaking and server certificate validation.
But now this seems not possible and I have to create my own user-defined truststore/keystore.

Can anybody let me know how to create a truststore/keystore to be used while communicating with an HTTPS server?

Once the truststore/keystore is created I should be able to install a self-signed server certificate and if needed remove it from the store programmatically using the class keystore.

Regards,
Mano

Comment: This discussion might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool?rq=1

Comment: See the Tools documentation for 'keytool'.