# Concatinating cert and key file so that it can be included in java cacert file

Tags: java, ssl, curl

We have been provided with certificate from our client for the CSR we have given to them.

Basically I have been provided with abc.pem and abc.cert files.

abc.key is the one which we have used to generate the CSR.

`openssl req -out abc.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout abc.key`

with following curl I was able to make a call to client.

`C:\Sanjay\Work\17MM\Curl\curl-7.43.0-win32\bin>curl --cert "abc.cert" --key abc.key  -X GET -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:applica
tion/json  -v "https://client.com"`

My questions:
We want to group the key file and cert file into one so that we can include it in cacert `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\security` so that we when we make a request via camel or apache http client it picks the certificate from cacert.

Please suggest!

Comment: The entire process is wrong from start to finish. You don't appear to understand the function of the `cacerts` file. The client should not have given you his private key, or you should not have generated it for him, whichever is the case. He *must* generate a new keypair *himself,* and a CSR as well. Instruct him if necessary. Leaking the private key is a *prima facie* security breach.

Answer (score 1):

The `cacerts` file is the default [truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643). It is a keystore in terms for file format, but it's used as a truststore (to verify the remote party's identity), not a keystore (to prove your identity to the remote party).

You shouldn't put your private key and End-Entity Certificate (EEC) in `cacerts`:

- It's good practice to separate keystore and truststore (since the truststore can be made public).
- There is no default keystore in Java. `cacerts` is only used as a truststore by default.

From the files you have, easiest option would be to build a PKCS#12 (`.p12`) file and use it with the `PKCS12` keystore type. You then can use the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` system property to point to it and `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12` for the type, and set `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` too, unless your client library has its own way of loading a keystore too.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. If I understand correctly, what you are suggesting is, from  abc.key and abc.cert create PKCS#12(.p12) file. and include the newly created file in keystore.