# How can I use the SSL in Spring Cloud gateway

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud-gateway

The configuration file is as follows：

```
server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: D:/https/portal.keystore
    key-store-password: 222222
  http2:
    enabled: true
```

the key-store generated by the java keytool.
the project can start-up normally,and when I request by the gateway,It is wrong.
the message as follows:

> io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record:
>   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
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1156)
>   [netty-handler-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]     at
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221)
>   [netty-handler-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
>   [netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
>   [netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
>   [netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
>   [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>   [netty-common-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why i was wrong,I config the spring cloud gateway https,but I request the gateway service without keysturst.store,it works erroneously.

So I req request the service with the keystrust.store,the problem has been solved.

Comment: can you place the step you did , cause i am unable to figure out

Comment: this means that you have to generate certificate for a client's trust store and share one. read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool