# NiFi ListenHTTP processor: Uses an unsupported protocol

Tags: ssl, https, apache-nifi

I have configured a **ListenHTTP** 1.7.0 processor in NiFi 1.7.0-RC1. It is listening on a custom port behind a reverse proxy. I have configured a **StandardRestrictedSSLContextService** with a JKS keystore and have added the keystore password. We have not configured the truststore as we don't expect to need mutual TLS. The certificate is signed by an internal enterprise CA and is (or should be!) trusted by the client.

When I test this with Chrome I receive the following:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> *my.server* uses an unsupported protocol.
>
> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
>
> Unsupported protocol
>
> The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

**Troubleshooting:**

- We have tried both **TLS** and **TLSv1.2** in the ListenHTTP processor.
- We have treid using `curl` (Linux) and `Invoke-WebRequest` (Windows) but have received variations on the bad cipher/SSL version message above.
- I don't see anything in the release notes suggesting that the ListenHTTP processor changed much since 1.7.0, so I'm assuming that I don't need to upgrade NiFi.

Can anyone suggest what to try next or explain why we see this error?

---

I have read the following:

- https://www.simonellistonball.com/technology/nifi-ssl-listenhttp/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes
- [Nifi: how to make ListenHTTP work with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695524/nifi-how-to-make-listenhttp-work-with-ssl)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you running on? Java 11 provides TLSv1.3, which is the default offering if you have generic `TLS` selected, but NiFi 1.7.0 doesn't support TLSv1.3 (and doesn't run on Java 11). So assuming you are running on Java 8, recent updates have introduced TLSv1.3 but should still provide for TLSv1.2. This can also indicate that the certificate you have provided is invalid or incompatible with the cipher suite list provided by the client. You can use `$ openssl s_client -connect <host:port> -debug -state -CAfile <path_to_your_CA_cert.pem>` to try diagnosing the available cipher suites & protocol versions. Adding `-tls1_2` or `-tls1_3`, etc. will restrict the connection attempt to the specified protocol version as well.

You should definitely upgrade from NiFi 1.7.0 -- it was released over 2 years ago, has known issues, and there have been close to 2000 bug fixes and features added since, including [numerous security issues](https://nifi.apache.org/security.html). NiFi 1.12.1 is the latest released version.

Comment: Thanks. We'll have a look and confirm re: Java a bit later. Thanks for the nudge about upgrading, we're not denying that. ;)