# Create a self signed certificate for localhost and import it in Glassfish

Tags: ssl, glassfish, keystore, self-signed-certificate, glassfish-5

I am developing a REST server that runs with Jersey on Glassfish, and I want to make it run on HTTPS on localhost.

I have found many tutorials for generating a CA cert, others for generating .cer / .crt / .key / .csr / ... files, others for generating a jks keystore.

But they do not answer my (very basic) question: how to generate a self signed certificate and use it in my app that runs on Glassfish, on localhost? **From scratch to the integration for a real usage**, without any prerequiresite having a crt, a jks or any other file.

(For information I use Linux)

Thanks

**EDIT**: I have finally created a certificate with the following commands

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name localhostServerCert -in localhost.crt -inkey localhost.key -out localhostP12Keystore.p12
```

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore localhostKeystore.jks -srckeystore localhostP12Keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias localhostServerCert
```

```
copy localhostKeystore.jks into /glassfish/domains/domain1/config
```

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore localhostKeystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks
```

And I have modified http-listener-2 in the admin console with certificate nickname `localhostServerCert`, but I got an error page on https://localhost:8181 (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

**EDIT 2** : I think there should be a problem with the certificate, since `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:8181` returns `no peer certificate available`, `No client certificate CA names sent`

Comment: Have you seen https://sectigo.com/resource-library/install-certificates-glassfish-server tutorial. Glassfish is a java server.  Java uses JKS to store ssl keys.  You have to generate a key and store it in JKS and then point to it when enabling https. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/

Comment: @Yan yes this is typically the kind of tutorial I don't like. They don't explain where do crt files come from (addtrustexternalcaroot.crt, XYZRSAAddTrustCA.crt, XYZRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt)

Comment: you don't really need to import  root and intermediate CA certificates to your trust store because you are doing local testing and will just approve the connection in the browser when it shows certificate is invalid

Comment: I think for your purpose you just need to create JKS via `keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit
-storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks` and then install it

Comment: @Yan Well, I have executed your cmd line into the glassfish domain config folder, then I edited the port and alias in the admin console and I replaced s1as by my own alias in domain.xml but it doesn't seem to work (website unaccessible). Moreover concerning the CA certificate, I will also hit my REST endpoints by using Insomnia and a React app.

Comment: I am not familiar with Glassfish not sure why it's it not starting.  On the react app side you would have to either disable SSL certification verification(not a good idea and only for local testing), get a real cert (let's encrypt?) or import the cert into the trust store of your computer.  Also, do you see error in glassfish logs?  Maybe will give you some ideas what's wrong.  Might be something wrong with the config.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool post .. maybe will give you a better understanding of  keystore vs trust store purpose

Comment: Depending on which version of GF you are using, take a look at either the Java EE 7 samples at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/servlet/security-clientcert or its Jakarta equivalent at https://github.com/javaee-samples/jakartaee-samples/tree/main/ee7/servlet/security-clientcert

Comment: @Yan I have finally generated and installed a self signed certificate, but `https://localhost:8181` still displays an `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error. In Glasfish logs there are many warnings indicating certificates expirations, but I read that it's normal (my certificate is not listed here)

Comment: @Yan I think there should be a problem with the certificate, since `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:8181` returns `no peer certificate available`, `No client certificate CA names sent` :(

Comment: It all make sense.  What are the errors on the server side?  have you seen this https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-glassfish/ ..  sorry stupid question :) http-listener-2 is set to port 8181 and TLS enabled .. are there any errors loading the cert.. maybe add the name of JKS in the config

Comment: @Yan Yes thanks I used this article to install the certificate :)
I cannot see any error in the logs. I also tried checking the SSL3 option, and adding the JKS name in the config, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: seems like it should just work.  Try to enable `<jvm-options>-Djavax.net.debug=SSL</jvm-options>` maybe will give you more information about SSL certs and if it loads the JKS. also check the JKS to see the key is there `keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystore.jks`

Comment: @Yan Thanks, it helped, I got new logs and an error: `http-listener-2(1), fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common` `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`. But I do not understand since there are ciphers in the logs: `Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x13:0x2, Unknown 0x13:0x3, Unknown 0x13:0x1, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0xaa, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, ..., TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**COMMON GOALS**

It can be useful to run with SSL locally, and I like to start with real world URLs. This can also help you to think ahead to your production deployment design, which often involves a Private PKI these days, based on a self issued Root CA.

Web and API domains can sometimes be related these days, eg if an API issues secure cookies for the web origin. So for localhost development I first define URLs such as these:

- https://api.mycompany.com
- https://web.mycompany.com

**DEVELOPER SETUP**

Then add entries such as this to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost web.mycompany.com api.mycompany.com
:1        localhost
```

Then, in terms of certificates, I produce these deployable files:

| Certificate | Filename | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Root CA | mycompany.ca.pem | The root certificate authority that is trusted by the Java runtime |
| Wildcard Certificate | mycompany.ssl.p12 | A password protected PKCS12 file deployed with the API |

My [Development Certificates Repository](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.developmentcertificates) has an example of how to issue the certs using openssl, including a bash script you can use for your own domains. Essentially this is a Private PKI for a development computer.

**CONFIGURING TRUST**

You then just need to trust the Root CA in the Java runtime used by Glassfish. Personally I tend to avoid JKS files where possible, since they are specific to Java, whereas PKCS12 files are a more portable concept:

```sh
sudo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool" -import -alias mycompanyroot -cacerts -file ~/Desktop/mycompany.ca.pem -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

**FURTHER DEVELOPER SETUP INFO**

These resources on a portable way to manage SSL development certs are provided below, which completes the architecture work:

- My [Developer SSL Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup/)
- My [Java API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot) uses the above certs and loads the wildcard certificate via this code, where a P12 file is used as a keystore:

```java
System.setProperty(
  "server.ssl.key-store", 
  configuration.getApi().getSslCertificateFileName());

System.setProperty(
  "server.ssl.key-store-password",
  configuration.getApi().getSslCertificatePassword());
```

**GLASSFISH**

If Glassfish based setups mean the API itself does not load the PKCS12 file, then there may be a specific task to import the PKCS12 file. Many systems provide a GUI or API option for loading a PKCS12 file into a keystore. This may result in a command like this being run, which you can do manually if needed:

```sh
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mycompany.ssl.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -v
```

Comment: Hi Gary, but loading the root certificate you generate were you able to call the glassfish https with any java program? Because i were struggling on that part and noticed that i had to remove from the root certificate the authority key identifier to make it work. Probably there is some setting in openssl but i took a "shortcut" to generate roots via code: https://github.com/kendarorg/JavaCaCertGenerator  what do you think?