Spring Boot SSL Configuration Error: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
I'm working on a Spring Boot project and trying to configure SSL using a self-signed certificate. I generated the certificate using the following command:
keytool -genkeypair -alias local_ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore local-ssl.p12 -validity 365 -ext san=dns:localhost -dname "CN=localhost, OU=TI, O=Eickrono, L=São Paulo, ST=SP, C=BR"

I followed these steps to generate and configure the SSL certificate for my Spring Boot application:

Generated a self-signed certificate using keytool:

keytool -genkeypair -alias local_ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore local-ssl.p12 -validity 365 -ext san=dns:localhost -dname "CN=localhost, OU=TI, O=Eickrono, L=São Paulo, ST=SP, C=BR"


Created a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using keytool:

keytool -certreq -alias local_ssl -keystore local-ssl.p12 -file local_ssl.csr


Created a temporary CA and signed the CSR using OpenSSL:

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out myCA.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 365 -out myCA.pem -subj "/CN=MyCA"
openssl x509 -req -in local_ssl.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out local_ssl.crt -days 365 -sha256


Imported the CA certificate and the signed certificate back into the keystore:

keytool -import -alias myCA -file myCA.pem -keystore local-ssl.p12 -trustcacerts
keytool -import -alias local_ssl -file local_ssl.crt -keystore local-ssl.p12


Updated my application.yml to use the keystore:

server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: local_ssl
    key-store: classpath:local-ssl.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-password: 20071991


Copied the local-ssl.p12 file to the src/main/resources directory of my project.
Expected Result: I expected my Spring Boot application to start successfully with SSL enabled, using the self-signed certificate I generated.

Actual Result: When I run my application, I encounter the following errors:
2024-09-16T15:43:44.975-03:00 INFO [35m35108[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[login-usuario-jwt.jar] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-09-16T15:43:44.998-03:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m35108[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[login-usuario-jwt.jar] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:469) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:990) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.eickrono.LoginUsuarioJWT.main(LoginUsuarioJWT.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:251) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:236) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1061) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1304) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:643) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1058) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1188) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:405) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

I’m not sure what I’m missing or doing wrong. How can I properly configure SSL in my Spring Boot application to avoid these errors?

C:\backup\Projetos\SSL>keytool -list -v -keystore local-ssl.p12 Enter
keystore password:
Keystore type: PKCS12 Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 2 entries
Alias name: local_ssl Creation date: 16 de set. de 2024 Entry type:
PrivateKeyEntry Certificate chain length: 2 Certificate[1]: Owner:
CN=localhost, OU=TI, O=Eickrono, L=São Paulo, ST=SP, C=BR Issuer:
CN=MyCA Serial number: 269b5287a49a6f3db26782514442c87d7dc82554 Valid
from: Mon Sep 16 15:14:45 ART 2024 until: Tue Sep 16 15:14:45 ART 2025
Certificate fingerprints:
SHA1: 9F:51:27:33:E4:5B:D4:0E:2F:F0:A1:F3:D1:9C:A4:21:9F:E6:7B:45
SHA256: D7:7A:42:92:7A:59:98:D3:3C:82:78:52:74:62:4B:6E:BD:C1:6B:9E:44:CD:92:C7:C5:85:D1:C6:B0:EA:54:C1
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
2048-bit RSA key Version: 3
Extensions:
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false AuthorityKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 42 15 8F 30 02 D7 49 06   81 FA 72 ED D4 6E 4E
9B  B..0..I...r..nN. 0010: 3B 8E 99 D5
;... ] ]
#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 9E B9 DB 08 9D 1C 7C BF   54 04 9F F1 8E 0F 8E
AE  ........T....... 0010: D0 99 7B 94
.... ] ]
Certificate[2]: Owner: CN=MyCA Issuer: CN=MyCA Serial number:
6ae26b43aa8c675e9cacc558ccbb6f811e75f5ff Valid from: Mon Sep 16
15:14:16 ART 2024 until: Tue Sep 16 15:14:16 ART 2025 Certificate
fingerprints:
SHA1: 85:17:2D:9C:CC:61:9A:65:3B:77:9E:08:6A:8F:6F:C6:AB:8D:E3:27
SHA256: 23:D6:D0:27:86:38:90:59:D1:FC:41:6E:0E:34:B3:BF:02:51:15:19:EC:7D:3A:AE:74:8F:1D:80:E5:80:2A:69
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
2048-bit RSA key Version: 3
Extensions:
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false AuthorityKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 42 15 8F 30 02 D7 49 06   81 FA 72 ED D4 6E 4E
9B  B..0..I...r..nN. 0010: 3B 8E 99 D5
;... ] ]
#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true BasicConstraints:[   CA:true   PathLen: no limit ]
#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 42 15 8F 30 02 D7 49 06   81 FA 72 ED D4 6E 4E
9B  B..0..I...r..nN. 0010: 3B 8E 99 D5
;... ] ]


Alias name: myca Creation date: 16 de set. de 2024 Entry type:
trustedCertEntry
Owner: CN=MyCA Issuer: CN=MyCA Serial number:
6ae26b43aa8c675e9cacc558ccbb6f811e75f5ff Valid from: Mon Sep 16
15:14:16 ART 2024 until: Tue Sep 16 15:14:16 ART 2025 Certificate
fingerprints:
SHA1: 85:17:2D:9C:CC:61:9A:65:3B:77:9E:08:6A:8F:6F:C6:AB:8D:E3:27
SHA256: 23:D6:D0:27:86:38:90:59:D1:FC:41:6E:0E:34:B3:BF:02:51:15:19:EC:7D:3A:AE:74:8F:1D:80:E5:80:2A:69
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
2048-bit RSA key Version: 3
Extensions:
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false AuthorityKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 42 15 8F 30 02 D7 49 06   81 FA 72 ED D4 6E 4E
9B  B..0..I...r..nN. 0010: 3B 8E 99 D5
;... ] ]
#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true BasicConstraints:[   CA:true   PathLen: no limit ]
#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 42 15 8F 30 02 D7 49 06   81 FA 72 ED D4 6E 4E
9B  B..0..I...r..nN. 0010: 3B 8E 99 D5
;... ] ]




Can you run keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/local-ssl.p12 -storetype PKCS12 and post the output.

C:\backup\Projetos\SSL>keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/local-ssl.p12 -storetype PKCS12
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /path/to/local-ssl.p12
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /path/to/local-ssl.p12
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:917)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:419)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:412)

/path/to/local-ssl.p12 should be the full path on your computers filesystem to the local-ssl.p12 file. Navigate to src/main/resources of your project and run keytool -list -v -keystore  local-ssl.p12 -storetype PKCS12

It is not possible to put all the content shown in a comment, so I put it in the problem description.

This might be because you need to add the CA to the JVM's truststore rather than the keystore.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool] for more details.

I did this, when I saw that it didn't work I opened this help request on stackoverflow
