# Difference between .keystore file and .jks file

Tags: keystore, jks

I have tried to find the difference between `.keystore` files and `.jks` files, yet I could not find it. I know `jks` is for "Java keystore" and both are a way to store key/value pairs.

Is there any difference or a preference to use one over another?

Answer (score 266):

Ultimately, `.keystore` and `.jks` are just file extensions: it's up to you to name your files sensibly.

Some application use a keystore file stored in `$HOME/.keystore`: it was usually implied that it was JKS file, since [JKS was the default keystore type in the Sun/Oracle Java security provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider), up to Java 8. Not everyone uses the `.jks` extension for JKS files, because it was implied as the default. [Since Java 9, the default format is PKCS#12](https://openjdk.org/jeps/229) (often with `.p12` or `pfx` extensions), but it's not clear whether all applications have caught up with that change. I'd recommend using the extension, just to remember which type to specify (if you need).

In Java, the word "keystore" can have either of the following meanings, depending on the context:

- the API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html
- a file (or other mechanism) that can be used to back this API
- a keystore as opposed to a truststore, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643

When talking about the file and storage, this is not really a storage facility for key/value pairs (there are plenty or other formats for this). Rather, it's a container to store cryptographic keys and certificates (I believe some of them can also store passwords). Generally, these files are encrypted and password-protected so as not to let this data available to unauthorized parties.

Java uses its [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider) class and related API to make use of a keystore ([whether it's file based or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157716/372643)). `JKS` is a Java-specific file format, but the API can also be used with other file types, typically PKCS#12. When you want to load a keystore, you must specify its keystore type. The conventional extensions would be:

- `.jks` for type `"JKS"`,
- `.p12` or `.pfx` for type `"PKCS12"` (the specification name is PKCS#12, but the `#` is not used in the Java keystore type name).

In addition, BouncyCastle also provides its implementations, in particular [BKS](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) (typically using the `.bks` extension), which is frequently used for Android applications.

Comment: I can confirm than changing the extension from .jks to .keystore will work. Please backup before doing it !!

Comment: sorry, still don't quite understand `.keystore` vs `.jks`.

Comment: @frank It depends on the context, they are just file name extensions. Often, they'll be the same actual type of file (a JKS file), but of course, file extensions are just an indication.

Comment: @Bruno `Keystore` has three meanings depends on the context(as described in answer). but for `.keystore` file and `.jks` file, they are the same(just file extension differents), both them contains public/private certificate and password, right?

Comment: Hi, Bruno we take your answer for the spanish version of SO, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162455/diferencias-entre-jks-y-keystore

Answer (score 109):

You are confused on this.

A `keystore` is a container of certificates, private keys etc.

There are specifications of what should be the format of this keystore and the predominant is the [#PKCS12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12)

JKS is Java's keystore implementation. There is also BKS etc.

These are all keystore **types**.

So to answer your question:

> difference between .keystore files and .jks files

There is none. JKS are keystore files. 
There is difference though between keystore **types**. E.g. `JKS` vs `#PKCS12`

Comment: I'd say the predominant *keystore* type is JKS, not PKCS#12, only because the word "keystore" is part of the Java terminology, only rarely used outside the context of Java. This being said, PKCS#12 files are quite common indeed (typically `.pfx` or `.p12`).

Comment: @Bruno:You mean the predominant type in Java applications.

Comment: No, I mean that the word "keystore" is mostly a Java word. Other applications/platforms rarely call the place/file where keys and certificates are store a "keystore". MS calls PKCS#12 files "Personal Information Exchange" files, for example. Others have names like "key chain" (OSX), "certificate database" (NSS), "certificate store", "key rings", ..., for the places where they store keys and certificates, not really "keystore".

Comment: @Bruno:I see what you mean.Good point.I hadn't thought of it like this before.Thanks

Answer (score 8):

One reason to choose .keystore over .jks is that Unity recognizes the former but not the latter when you're navigating to select your keystore file (Unity 2017.3, macOS).

Comment: What is this 'unity' you referred to. I have same issue of .jks file not getting identified by my java agent.

Comment: @Salman I'm referring to the "Unity" game engine (https://unity3d.com).