# Converting a Eclipse keystore file into a .jks file to add it Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-keystore, jks

I need help finding a way to get a Eclipse keystone file that has the credential for an app to be converted to an .jks file of be used to signed for the new version of the app.

The computer used to create the original app was destroyed but the keystore file was saved. i recreated the app on but this time in Android Studio instead of Eclipse, but now i need to get the keystone file that has the information and credentials to be coverted to a .jks file so i can use it and submit the new version of the app to the Google Play store.

If there are other ways to add the credentials/certificate to the Android Studio file then i would like to know

Thanks

Comment: Have you got the certificate file (the file ends with .cert)? Than click on generate apk on studio and than select the keystore instead to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file), "Ultimately, .keystore and .jks are just file extensions: it's up to you to name your files sensibly. Some application use a keystore file stored in $HOME/.keystore: it's usually implied that it's a JKS file, since JKS is the default keystore type in the Sun/Oracle Java security provider."
Maybe you could try to just rename your file?