# SSL Implementation using java keytool

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I got my keystore file of jks type using keytool commands. now i need to get a self signed certificate to test at development. I am  unable to understand how to generate certificate i tried by using keytool commands but i am getting exceptions like "illegal option, file not found" . So, can anyone please specify the right way to do it? I have followed [apacheSSLconfig](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)
but i couldn't get the .cer file with those commands. Thanks in advance

Comment: "File not found" looks like you might have specified incorrect paths. What _exactly_ have you done and where are your files located?

Comment: yeah, i understood the mistake i have done thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.. **Creating keystore**

```
keytool -genkey -alias name1 -keyalg RSA -keystore name1.keystore -storepass password -keypass keypassword -storetype JKS -keysize 1024
```

`name1` - alias name (you can give your own alias) 
`name1.keystore` - keystore file name to be created (you can specify location like c:\name1.keystore) 
`password` - keystore password 
`keypassword` - keystore key password (private key)

2.. **Export certificate**

```
keytool -export -alias name1 -keystore name1.keystore -rfc -file name1.cert -storepass password
```

`name1.keystore` - keystore location 
`name1.cert` - Certificate name that to be exported (you can specify full path to where you want to xport the certificate) 
`password` - keystore password

3.. **Import Certificate to Truststore**

```
keytool -import -alias name1 -file name1.cert -keystore name1.TrustStore -storepass truststorepassword
```

`name1.cert` - location of the certificate exported before in step. 
`name1.TrustStore` - Truststore name (can specify full path) 
`truststorepassword` - Trust store password

Comment: thanks, i am done with 1,2 steps . Is it necessary to implement third step too ??, as i am trying for a self signed certificate to test my application locally.

Comment: Third step is necessary for server/client application. Client should have truststore to connect with the server or other client SSL services.

Comment: Refer [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/09/difference-between-truststore-vs-keyStore-Java-SSL.html)

Comment: You'll need the server cert if you want to use it in an android app. For browsers it is not mandatory but you'll get a biiiig warning message saying they don't know you.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks. For browsers, you need to add the certificate to trusted location in your machine to avoid such warning messages.

Answer (score 1):

First you must understand that keytool handles java keystore files which is an Oracle container format for certificates and keys ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file)). Note that each entry in a keystore will have an alias you must refer to when manipulating the keystore. So when you run:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

you're basically creating a keystore which contains a selfsigned certificate aliased as 'selfsigned'. If you need the actual certificate file you may export it from the keystore with:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore  /path/to/keystore.jks -storepass <password> -alias selfsigned -file ./name.cer
```

as already mentioned. But you don't need to. Following the instructions in the [Configuration section](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html%20configuration) in Tomcat's documentation all you need to do is to create the keystore and configure the server to use it by editing the NIO connector:

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="path/to/keystore.jks" keystorePass="<the password>"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Make sure the user running Tomcat has read permissions on the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a self signed certificate, you do keytool -genkey as is explained [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html).  then, if you want the certificate in a cer file, you can export it using keytool -exportcert 
example:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore  /path/to/keystore.jks -storepass <password> -alias <name> -file ./name.cer
```