# Android Generate signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

[Android Key Generator screen in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OW0R.jpg)

When I try to generate a signed apk in Android Studio I get this screen to generate a new key. I have made a folder 'Android Key' and when I set path to this folder the wizard is asking for File name   .jks. Where can I find .jks ?

Comment: Looks like is the same as .keystore look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file

Comment: Find out more about signing apk using keystore [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a signed apk, you will need a keystore. Follow this procedure to generate a keystore.

1. On the menu bar, click **Build > Generate Signed APK**.
2. On the **Generate Signed APK Wizard** window, click **Create new** to create a new keystore.
3. On the **New Key Store** window, provide the required information.
4. Save **fileName.jks** file and keep it safe.

Use this keystore file for signing your file in future.

Comment: Thanks. When I changed the  default destination folder C:/Users/app_name/android  to a new folder it worked.

Answer (score 5):

**Signing Your App in Android Studio**

To sign your app in release mode in Android Studio, follow these steps:

1.On the menu bar, click Build > Generate Signed APK.

2.On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, click Create new to create a new keystore.
If you already have a keystore, go to step 4.[image]

3.On the New Key Store window, provide the required information as shown in figure 1.
Your key should be valid for at least 25 years, so you can sign app updates with the same key through the lifespan of your app.

4.On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, select a keystore, a private key, and enter the passwords for both. Then click Next.[image]

5.On the next window, select a destination for the signed APK and click Finish.

[image]