# How to create a singular .keystore file

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, godot

I'm trying to make a .keystore file in Android Studio 3.0.1, but whenever I try to "Generate Signed APK", I always end up with a JKS file. I need a debug.keystore file for a game I am making in Godot, and will be releasing the game onto the Google Play Store. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041012/2911458 might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Android SDK installed, the debug.keystore is unique to your machine for development purposes only.

On Windows 10 it is located at: `C:\Users\{username}\.android\debug.keystore`

Linux/ Mac OS: `~/.android/debug.keystore`

That should allow you to deploy an APK to a test device or emulator.  When you are ready to put in on the play store, you need to always sign the apk with the same key in a keystore you generate.  The .JKS file is the release keystore.