# Lost keystore file for app (but have Google Play App Signing enabled)

Tags: android

I have lost the original `keystore` file used to sign my app with.

My app has Google Play App Signing enabled.

If I contact Google Support is it possible to reset the key so that I can continue uploading to this package? I'm hoping that I can do this because App Signing is enabled, but am not sure if my assumption is correct.

Comment: This could be usefull
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odv_1fxt9BI

Comment: Windows: found mine using `Get-Childitem -Path C:\ -Include *keystore* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems it should work.
"Manage your app signing keys
With Google Play App Signing, you can securely manage your app signing keys for new or existing apps. Keys are stored on the same secure infrastructure Google uses to store its own keys.

If you lose your keystore or think it may be compromised, Google Play App Signing makes it possible to request a reset to your upload key. If you're not enrolled in Google Play App Signing and lose your keystore, you'll need to publish a new app with a new package name."
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Instructions at the end of the page:

"Reset your upload key
Step 1: Generate a new private key and upload certificate
Step 2: Contact our support team"

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raanan. "You lost your private key" - am I correct in saying that's the `.keystore` file?

Comment: Yes. Usually your private key will be in a file with `.keystore` extension. I have seen someone saving it as `.cer`. (as it's just a name)

Comment: Good Luck with that. Read and follow the instructions in the link.

Comment: Thank God. I had the right keystore after all but I wasn't looking at the error from Google closely enough. I had signed it with multiple accidentally and just needed to delete and resign once. Thanks again for your help - I'm backing my key up in 100 different places now because I don't want to panic like that again.

Comment: I lost a keystore for an App made in 2014. Does this mean I can not leverage this approach to update the app on play store?

Comment: This answer is correct, google would not reset our private key and would not delete our old app, our only solution was to use a new package name.  We were not enrolled in google play signing(with a separate upload key).

Comment: This fixed my issue and my keys were reset. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: @Raanan It's saving `jks` file, how I get `keystore` file from this? Google already reset it for me after I sent `pem` file...

Comment: @Idan JKS is a keystore file. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file

Answer (score 1):

If you lost your Signing key, then Google provide a way,

Just contact Google via

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key

[image: Quesiton asked by the Google]

Just fill out the form after, and you will receive the mail
[image: Reply after submission query to google]

**After a few hours Google replies to create a new key and send the key to this reply**
[image: Google Reply after few hour]

**After a few hours Google reply that the new key will be valid in a few days**

**After a few day keys will be activated and now you can update your app**