# How to make apk after updating key on playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I am forget my keystore file, So I requsted to google support team to update my key file.

Here’s how to generate and register a new upload key:
Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.
Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
Reply to this email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file.

After this process I provided .pem file to support team. And I got mail that "The new key will be usable from: 2020-01-09 06:18:56 UTC." But after that I made apk using same keystore file and upload to playstore so I get error message that finger print is not matched.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkRm9.png)

Please help me after after key how can I make apk using keystore/.pem file. So that my app will updated.

Thanks
Pummy Sinha

Comment: Hi @pummy, You can download the keystore file from git if you have maintained a repo on bitbucket.

Comment: No, I don't have keystore file on git. But I update keystore file on google play store but again I get error message fingerprint is not matched.

Comment: Hope this helps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613498/lost-keystore-file-for-app-but-have-google-play-app-signing-enabled)