# How to recover password of existing keystore file?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I signed my android application with a Keystore file. I fill the `Google Protect Appeals` form and the `'blocked by play protect'` error disappears. Now I have made some changes and for re-generating the release apk, unfortunately, I got the wrong password error for the Keystore file. I can't use `executionHistory.bin` because I delete the .gradle and .idea directories.
Is there any way to recover the password from `.jks` file? It's very necessary for me.

Comment: If you could get the password out of the keystore file, then what good would it be to have a password at all?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't recover the password from a `.jks` file. It is a protective file if anyone can recover the password it would be useless.

You can however change the whole keystore: [Lost keystore file for app (but have Google Play App Signing enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613498/lost-keystore-file-for-app-but-have-google-play-app-signing-enabled)