# How to Sign android app with private_key.pepk

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-keystore

I have an app in Google Play now I need to publish new version 2 of this app.

how can I Sign android app with private_key.pepk ?

I lost Java keystore (.jks or .keystore) I only have private_key.pepk

Answer (score 2):

The file private_key.pepk is your private key encrypted with a key that only Google can decrypt. It is used only for transferring the key to Google when you enroll in Play Signing.

So you can't extract the private key from this file, but you can enroll in App Signing by Play by providing this file to Google and they'll be able to sign your app on your behalf. You will need to set a different upload key as well (you'll be prompted at the end of the enrollment) so you can sign the APKs or App Bundles you upload to Play with a new keystore you will have created.

Answer (score 0):

Refer here, this may solve the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613539/6543693

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem with google play you can't use new Key with your old app

now I only have private_key.pepk

Comment: Oh, Sorry I thought that it's new