# Lost keystore password but still have private_key.pepk : Google signin app

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, sign, jks

I lost my password of the keystore :( and I can't upload update anymore on the Google Play Store.

I cannot force brut it, because I know it has 20 caracters, it will be very long to force it.

I still have the private_key.pepk, is there a way to create a new keystore and insert the private_key.pepk into it to sign the app ? (I'm not confortable with all those things).

Can I find the password saved on Android Studio ? I might have a computer with the password saved in it.

Thank you

Comment: I think you can't upload with new key. check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62961439/10778405

Comment: Check this. This might help. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset it for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I contacted Google Play Support, i'll tell you if it worked

Comment: Ok it worked, i created a new keystore and sent them the upload certificate (.pem) generated. They checked my identity then few days later, i was able to make new updates on playstore