# Google Play Console installation failed SHA1

Tags: android

I had a site where I compiled my game and converted it to apk. auto signed there. I was not getting sha1 vs warning. However, the site was closed and when I tried to sign myself I got a warning that sha1 would be the same.
not loaded

You have installed an APK signed with a different certificate than your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with certificates (fingerprints):

[SHA1: ORIGINAL FINGERPRINT HERE]

and the certificates used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprints:

[SHA1: THE NEW FINGERPRINT IS HERE] ''

I don't have a .jks file, I don't have alias and password. I saved the files in the photo while uploading my first game in 2017. Can I get jks from them? how can i sign?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARo2K.png)

Comment: if you have published a version on play store and have lost old key then you can get new certificate and key from play store.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the "REQUEST NEW VERSION OF KEY" option. Frankly, I was a little hesitant about this option in case I might encounter an irreversible result. Does it give me the jks file? Or is it just giving certificate and pem file like in the photo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613498/lost-keystore-file-for-app-but-have-google-play-app-signing-enabled

Comment: I don't want to publish with a new package name. I have the files in the photo. I guess I need to communicate with google play.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place that site might not have given you the `release` certificate and key. they might have given you the `debug` certificate and key. so when you try to sign the app again with those cert key pair you get the error.

That's how such sites i earn i belive

If you have already made a valid release in play console then you can issue a new certificate key pair from play console.

follow the link for extra info => https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-a-new-Certificate-Keystore-key-after-losing-the-key-of-my-Android-app

Comment: I downloaded the certificates from google game console. Your links seem useful. I will investigate the method of signing with the pem file in the photo without creating a new certificate. no password and alias.

I still have the option to "REQUEST NEW VERSION OF KEY". If I follow this process I may not need the old certificates and it will let me update :(

I don't know how to code. I make games with drag and drop method and I have difficulty in such operations. Thank you for your understanding

Comment: @onurdemir you ll get new certificate and keys and you can sign your source code with those and then everything ll work. dont get demotivated. the game has not even started yet. android is a big thing. there is so much to learn. start playing with android studio ;)