# how to update exsting android apk with pepk file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, version, jks

I want to update an existing android application on playstore but I don't have JKS file (lost in old pc), but I have "private_key.pepk" file, alias, and key password and debug.keystore.

can I still update my app with if yes how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost keystore file for app (but have Google Play App Signing enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613498/lost-keystore-file-for-app-but-have-google-play-app-signing-enabled)

Comment: no its not what im looking for