# Generate/Convert .keystore file from .jks file as #unity does not accept .jks

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-developers-console

My app was signed in the Google developer console. Now Google has deleted my .keystore file and has sent me .jks file to sign my app, which Unity3d does not accept.

Is there any way to convert that .jks file to a .keystore file? or any other way to apply the update?

Comment: What happens if you just treat your .jks as a .keystore file (just rename)? According to this answer they should be the same type of file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file

Answer (score 5):

From the following link:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-keystore-file.460793/

> Latest versions of Android Studio prepares the keystore file with .jks extension but Unity looks for a file with keystore extension. Renaming the file with .keystore extension might help.