# JKS and KEYSTORE

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, keystore, jks

I'm trying to generate an apk to publish on Play Store with Unity.
I've had to regenerate the keystore, cause I've lost the previously, so I've had to do it with Android Studio to sent the CEM to Google Support.
The problem is that Android Studio makes .jks and Unity asks me a .keystore file. How can I convert it to build an apk file to publish on Google Developer Console?
Thank you!

Comment: I could be wrong but as far as I know `.keystore` and `.jks` are just different extensions for same file format. I believe all you have to do is rename the extension.

Comment: I think so. On 13 June I could answer this. I hope someone has some certain answer!

Answer (score 0):

From this other answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010561/9248718

You should be good to go to sign your app with the .jks file.

If you lost your old keystore I think your only solution will be to just create a new one and publish your app as another independent app as [the Google Docs say](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#top_of_page)

Comment: Google Support says me to do this procedure instead to republish it. But how I said, Android Studio create a .jks and Unity requires a .keystore! TT____TT

Comment: Try `cp yourfile.jks yourfile.keystore`