# Should I enter the same password for an existing keystore?

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to update my android project. I created the update in a second project,. The keystore's passwords are in the first. I do not know the password for the keystore. I can use the same keystore with a different password and generate the app.aab to upload to the playstore. I still don't understand what's wrong with connecting the android studio with play store account, Won't it be easier if google allows us to store passwords just like chrome?.

Can I change the password using the java tools for they keystore and sign the app and update it??

Update:Ok, I found the keystore password, just do not know the alias password. any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an active Google Play App Signing, you can actually reset the keystore.

Create a new keystore, example : `upload_certificate.keystore`

Change the file `upload_certificate.keystore` to `upload_certificate.pem`
with the following command:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias key0 -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore upload_certificate.keystore
```

Then contact the Google Play Support Team through [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) using a Google Play account that is used to create and upload the latest APK updates. Tell the problem (in english please) and don't forget to attach the file upload_certificate.pem

Although you can reset the keystore, the process is not instant, it takes 2 days to reset the keystore and upload it again. The problem is, when I need critical update, the method as I explained cannot be used. Therefore, always backup the keystore in a safe place.

Comment: why is my keystore file in jks format, and yours in .keystore format?

Comment: And Is there no other way to retrieve it?. I have both android studio projects in my system, now the old project is also not generating the signed apk., it shows some keystore tampered error.

Comment: for the difference .jks and .keystore format you can see it in full [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file)

Comment: So far I have not found another way, but a way to create a new keystore is one of the main solutions for now. A few days ago I lost the same thing and it made me back up my .keystore file.

Comment: I have the keystore file,but I just lost the password. . keystore files are .jks extension or . keystore extension?

Comment: It's unfortunate, but when you lose the password to your keystore, your application is orphaned. The only thing you can do is resubmit your app to the market under a new key and don't forget to backups your keystore and writes the passwords down in a safe location.

Comment: You can see other references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

Comment: But there seems to be a password in the android studio generate signed apk window in the old project. Can I not copy that?. and btw, i used the keytool to open the jks, when it asked for entering the password, i didn't enter any. and the keystore file opened., but there's no password in it.