# Can I use .jks file instead of .keystore file in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, keystore, jks

I am trying to get a .aab file after creating a simple app in react native. Now in order to get that I need to make a .keystore file. Now as this app will replace a previous app in play store(which was created using Dart) I need to use the previous app's keystore file which is in .jks format. Now can I use this .jks file or do I need to convert this .jks file to .keystore file? Is there any I can convert this .jks file to .keystore file?

Comment: No need to convert, you can use jks instead of keystore file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to convert the .jks file to .keystore because JKS meaning `Java Keystore` already, you can use whatever you want.

You can check this question to learn the differences between the two: [Difference between .keystore file and .jks file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file)

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted? Maybe an upvote? It would be great, thanks ^^

Comment: can"t do upvote. don"t have the previlage